# Fastest algorithm to perform N*M iterations in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I am not an algorithm person, so pardon the naivety of the question.

I have a list A containing elements 100K elements. I have another list B containing 100K elements. Let's say a is an element from list A, b is the element from list B. I want to find out those (a, b) combinations whose sum is less than 100.

One obvious way to do this is following:

```
results = []
for a in A:
    for b in B:
        if (a+b) < 100:
            results.append((a,b))
```

but the time complexity of this approach is O(n*m) = 100K * 100K which is quite large. Is there any fast algorithm which can compute the desired output more efficiently - in terms of memory and time. If yes, can it be implemented in python?

Comment: I suppose you could sort the lists. Reminds me of the knapsack problem.

Comment: you could hold the 2000k elements in RAM. Sort them and with a little thinking you can come up with a fast solution at that state.

Comment: If you want to find all the actual pairs, then there is no faster method as the final output can be as big as 100k * 100k.

Comment: nope, there IS a faster way.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre How can you create the final list which has 100k * 100k elements in less time? I believe the algorithm you are thinking will count the number of pairs rather than producing each one.

Comment: @merlyn There are 5 positive integers smaller than 6, but I didn't have to think about all 5 to come up with that. Well, unless you want the complete list of them, indeed.

Comment: @Nelfeal That's kind of my point. You can find the number of solutions, not the solutions themselves. That could very well be what the OP actually wanted, but in the question, he is calculating the actual list.

Comment: @merlyn True, but you could surely imagine storing all the solutions without listing them all. You can group them in some way. And if the number of solutions can be 100k*100k = 10G, you would be hard pressed to do that unless you have quite a bit of RAM.

Comment: @merlyn: your are right that an output of size 100K*100K could not be produced faster. But I assumed that the output in most cases is much smaller. And you can reduce the complexity of the algorithm to the size of the output rather than to the square of the input.

Comment: everyone, thank you so much for your comments, many eye-opening answers. may I ask a follow-up question? How will the approach suggested by @Nelfeal will change if suppose I have to perform something on strings instead of numbers, example find all such pairs if "hello" in "string_a" + "string_b"

Comment: @userxxx , you should not ask a follow up question in the comments. Instead, ask a new question and reference this question if necessary.

Comment: @userxxx Finding all pairs of strings `a, b` such that `concatenation(a, b) = target` is even easier: only some `a`s can serve as prefix, and only some `b`s can serve as suffix. But the problem is quite different, so the solution is also quite different.

Answer (score 9):

Sort both lists (`O(n log n)` and `O(m log m)`, maybe less if the values are constrained).

Then, you can simply find, for each `a` in `A`, the largest `b` in `B` such that `(a+b) < 100`. Every smaller `b` will also satisfy that condition.

Finding the largest `b` for some `a` can be done using binary search to find a lower bound in `B`. And by starting with the largest `a` going down, you can preserve the list of `b`s corresponding to the previous `a`, since the sum is going to be smaller.

Comment: yeah, knapsack problem all right. Needs special bisect implementation. That's the way.

Comment: "Every smaller b will also satisfy that condition." this can be `O(m)` to append them all to a list. That statement just obfuscates that part of the time complexity.

Comment: appending would, but a slice should be O(1), correct?

Comment: @C.Nivs when you combine slices for each element in A, you still hit `O(m)`.

Comment: @Alex Well of course you can't go below q operations if you have q solutions and want them all in a list. I figure you either group them, or you know constraints that imply q isn't too large.

Comment: "you can simply find, for each a in A, the largest b in B such that (a+b) < 100": yes, but using bisection, so it's not that easy. If you use a linear search, the complexity is the same as the original problem.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Well it's not that complex either, binary searches are well-known, especially in programming. Pointed it out nonetheless.

Comment: @Nelfeal probably not to someone who is asking this question.

Comment: @Nelfeal why sort A?

Comment: @KevinOlree Good question. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't get better than that in the worst case. Consider a pathological case where every combination of A and B must be appended to the list:

```
A = list(range(0, -n, -1))
B = list(range(0, -m, -1))
```

Because each pair must be appended, you are doing `O(m * n)` operations.

If you only needed to count the number of combinations this could be a different story.

Answer (score 0):

As your criteria is that `a + b < 100` that can be defined as range. In this case I defined it as `wanted_result_range = range(0, 100)` as your lists A and B are containing only positive numbers so results will be only positive values.

Run the following script and you will see how much faster is my approach than "frontal" one that you have mentioned. My solution will be bad if wider wanted_result_range is defined.

```
import timeit
# http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/timeit.html

print "\nTiming execution times\n"

version1="""
results1 = []
list_A = range(1000)
list_B = range(1000)
wanted_result_range = range(0, 100)
d1 = {} 
l3 = []
for key in list_A: 
    d1[key] = True # Value associated to key is not important and can be any value 
for wanted_result in wanted_result_range:
    for key2 in list_B: 
        if ((wanted_result-key2) in d1): 
            results1.append((key2,wanted_result-key2))
"""
print("Version 1 - Hash table (dictionary) approach")
print(timeit.repeat(version1, number=10, repeat=4))
print('END Version 1\n')

version2="""
results2 = []
list_A = range(1000)
list_B = range(1000)
for a in list_A:
    for b in list_B:
        if (a+b) < 100:
            results2.append((a,b))
"""
print("Version 2 - Frontal approach")
print(timeit.repeat(version2, number=10, repeat=4))
print('END Version 2\n')
```

Comment: Nowhere in the question is stated that `A` and `B` contain only positive numbers.

Comment: @Nelfeal This can be used with negative numbers too.

Comment: Really? Good luck making it work with the "wanted result range" being `[-inf, 100]`.